# change environment variable in mac

Tags: java, macos, java-8, environment-variables

I am new to this mac world. I just installed jdk 8 on my mac and want to set $JAVA_HOME environment variable. I guess I should set it in .bash_profile file.

but it seems, my machine does not have this file and I don't know from where this $PATH variable coming from. Can't I have all env variables listed in one window or by one command just like windows?

how do I do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at .bash_profile under your user directory - e.g. on my machine it's /Users/mikep/.bash_profile - if it doesn't exist, feel free to create it.

Here I assign environmental variables using export - e.g.

> export JAVA_HOME=/Pathtomyjavainstall
>
> export PATH=$PATH:/PathtomyJDKbindirectory

Then execute:

> source ~/.bash_profile

To reload the environmental variables.

To check that they're set you can use echo from a Terminal window - e.g.

> echo $JAVA_HOME

Results in:
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_71.jdk/Contents/Home

Comment: so if /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_73.jdk/Contents/Home
is the output I receive after executing ls -l `which java`,

then both the params "Pathtomyjavainstall" and "PathtomyJDKbindirectory" should be the same path that I mentioned above right?

Comment: Path to my java install would be this - correct.

JDK bin directory would be the /bin directory under Home - so:

/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_71.jdk/Contents/Home/bin

Answer (score 0):

If you do not see a .bash_profile in your home directory (`$HOME` or `~`) when you do an `ls -a`, you should have a `.profile` which isn't bash-specific; but does the same job (execute on startup)

To see *all* the environment variables, just type `set` into the terminal. Or `set|less` if the list is too long.